# BootStrap Responsive Background image with text on it is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm getting started with BootStrap 3 and trying to use a background image with text on it. At same time I want it to be reponsive but it seems there is some issue with the way I implemented it. I'm able to get it work for normal desktop but when I try to emulate on a mobile device, text goes outside of background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/cn5guyt4/2/

```
<div id="front-landing">
   <div class="container jumbotron hero-unit">
       <h2 class="h1"><span>"Sample Test"</span></h2>
       <h3 class="-sub-title">
          <span>"Sample Test text 2"</span>
       </h3>
    </div>
</div>

.hero-unit {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-P5uqUWLgZmA/UtQDdtahipI/AAAAAAAAF3E/IgvARwfxAlw/s1600/seamless-stone-background.jpg') 50% 80% no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 2.625em;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
  margin-bottom: 0.571em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.-sub-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span { 
    background-color: white; 
}

h3 span { 
    background-color: white; 
}
```

Can someone help me to figure out what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: You should read the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/) your code is not very bootstrap friendly (eg: col>col-sm-4 )

Comment: just updated the JSFiddle Link

Answer (score 2):

In your `hero-unit class`, the `background-size` set to `100%` but it should be `cover` instead. That made a huge difference: [see bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7NLruHVv32).

I think what you are really trying to do is get the jumbotron of bootstrap to have a background picture. Why is your jsfiddle code different from the code you posted here? there is a wild margin of difference. My fix is using the code above.

### [Working bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OGDYYy6pSM#)

```
<div id="front-landing">
   <div class="container jumbotron ">
       <h2 class="h1"><span>"Sample Test"</span></h2>
       <h3 class="-sub-title">
          <span>"Sample Test text 2"</span>
       </h3>
    </div>
</div>

.h1 {
  font-size: 2.625em;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
  margin-bottom: 0.571em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-P5uqUWLgZmA/UtQDdtahipI/AAAAAAAAF3E/IgvARwfxAlw/s1600/seamless-stone-background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.-sub-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span { 
    background-color: white; 
}

h3 span { 
    background-color: white; 
}
```

Comment: I have edited the jsFiddle Link. Also, by changing background-size to cover, I'm still not able to solve the problem. If I open this in a mobile view, the text goes out of image.

Comment: see the working bootply link. the text stays in the div. @dark_shadow

Comment: yeah, checked that though the text stays inside the image but image itself is not adjusted to the size of small screen. I have updated the image link in bootply. Can you please check ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set image as a background-image

```
.imageAndText img{
    width: 100%;
   background: no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

for text you can use col-xs-12 or work write individual  media query

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle Link. Can you please take a look at it.

Comment: .hero-unit {
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-top: 15px;
            background: url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-P5uqUWLgZmA/UtQDdtahipI/AAAAAAAAF3E/IgvARwfxAlw/s1600/seamless-stone-background.jpg') 50% 80% no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
           width:100%;
        }

Comment: always use
 background-size: cover;
width:100%;

never set height